# I keep getting an error saying "expected declaration"

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm following a tutorial to make a version of flappy bird. I'm using swift and this error keeps coming up. The "addChild(self.myFloor1) keeps saying expected declaration error. What did I do wrong?

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
var myBackground = SKSpriteNode()
var myFloor1 = SKSpriteNode()
var myFloor2 = SKSpriteNode()
    addChild(self.myFloor1)


    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    myBackground = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
    myBackground.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;

    myBackground.position = CGPointMake(100, 0);

    self.backgroundColor = SKColor(red: 80.0/255.0, green: 192.0/255.0, blue: 203.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        addChild(self.myBackground)

    myFloor1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "floor")
    myFloor2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "floor")
    myFloor1.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
    myFloor1.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    myFloor2.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
    myFloor2.position = CGPointMake(myFloor1.size.width-1, 0);

        }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

Comment: Well what is addChild? It's not defined anywhere.

Comment: addChild is a method of SKNode. But it must not be called outside of any method.

Comment: I meant to post this addChild(self.myFloor1)
addChild(self.myFloor2)

Comment: where do i need to place addChild(self.myFloor1)?

Comment: addChild is a method(function) that adds a sprite to the scene. You can't use addChild on the class itself. You put it right under the class variables, so Xcode thinks you're making a new variable/function for the class. addChild should always be called inside a function such as didMoveToView or other functions you make.

Answer (score 2):

Declaration refers to creating a new variable or method. The location you wrote addChild() seems as if you're creating a new variable. For example, let's look at the following simple class.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var myBackground = SKSpriteNode()
}
```

The variable myBackground is being declared as a new variable. You are creating a new instance of an SKSpriteNode object. SKSpriteNode is also a class. Now let's add a method to your GameScene class that prints hello. All the things you declare in the class is referred as being in the top level, which is where you create variables and functions, etc.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var myBackground = SKSpriteNode()

    //This is a method/function of the class GameScene
    func sayHello() {
        print("Hello.")
    }

    //CAN'T CALL ITS OWN METHOD AT THE TOP LEVEL
    sayHello()
}
```

To help you understand, addChild is a method/function of the SKNode class.

```
class SKNode: UIResponder {
    func addChild(node: SKNode) {...}
}
```

So when you have something like you have it, it doesn't make sense because addChild is a function and you can't call a function at the top level of a class.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var myBackground = SKSpriteNode()
    var myFloor1 = SKSpriteNode()
    //CAN'T CALL METHOD ON TOP LEVEL OF CLASS
    addChild(self.myFloor1)
}
```

Xcode thinks you're creating a new function called addChild, so it's expecting you to declare it by using the "func" keyword, which is why it's giving you the error, but obviously you're not creating a function call addChild, you need to call it.

You have to call addChild() inside a function/method because it calls the SKNode's addChild method.

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
addChild(self.myFloor1)
```

You are calling a method, which must be done inside another method declaration.

Within your class declaration, the "highest level" "things" need to be declared as something: "var", "let", "func".  Then within a "func", you can call your addChild method.

That's why you are getting the error: At that "class" level, it's expecting only things that you can specify what they are.  Which here, you are not.  You are trying to directly call that method.

What I suspect you may want, is add the viewDidLoad method and call addChild from within there.  Or something like that...whatever makes sense for your view lifecycle.

Comment: how would it look when i add it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the lifecycle for sprit kit, but my guess would be to simply move the offending addChild line to the end of the didMoveToView method (right after setting myFloor2.position).

Comment: Thank you so much I've been overthinking it! This is my very first project so I'm new to everything

Comment: @CameronBillingsley addChild needs to be inside a function. You can't have addChild outside of a function in the class because then you're saying that addChild is a variable or function that you're adding to the class itself, which you're not. I would study how classes in Swift work before you do tutorials.